# How to translate Deflection Tracking component?

Tags: translation-workbench

I have created a Deflection Tracking component. 
(https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_deflection_tracking.htm&type=5)

I would like to translate the text I provided. How could I do that? I cannot find the proper object in the Translation Workbench.